# Confirm regex for validating password policy

Tags: php, security, regex

I have the following password policy:

- At least 8 characters in length
- At least one digit
- At least one *special** character

**I consider any character that is not a letter, digit or space to be a special character.*

I've come up with the following regex for enforcing this policy, and it seems to be working.

```
^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]).{8,}$
```

Are there any drawbacks or pitfalls with my regex?

Comment: Apart from it allowing passwords without letters, I think it is fine :)

Comment: Keep it, it's the simplest way with not so hard regex.

Answer (score 2):

I find the problem with regular expressions is how hard they are to read, and how quickly they become very complicated.

Instead of using a single regex to check for all your conditions I would define a class for a the password that you can then set a series of simple rules for.

This does use static methods, which is not to everyone's taste.

```php
interface Rule
{

    public function check(string $value): bool;
}

class LengthRule implements Rule
{
    protected $length;

    /**
     * LengthRule constructor.
     *
     * @param $length
     */
    public function __construct($length)
    {
        $this->length = $length;
    }

    public function check(string $value): bool
    {
        return mb_strlen($value) >= 8;
    }
}

class DigitRule implements Rule
{
    public function check(string $value): bool
    {
        return preg_match('/\d/', $value) === 1;
    }
}

class SpecialCharacterRule implements Rule
{
    public function check(string $value): bool
    {
        return preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d ]/', $value) === 1;
    }
}

class Password
{
    /** @var Rules[] */
    protected static $rules = [];

    protected $value;

    /**
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function __construct(string $value)
    {
        foreach (static::$rules as $rule) {
            if (false === $rule->check($value)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("The value doesn't" .
                    " match all rules.");
            }
        }

        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @param Rule $rule
     */
    public static function registerRule(Rule $rule)
    {
        self::$rules[] = $rule;
    }

}

Password::registerRule(new LengthRule(8));
Password::registerRule(new DigitRule());
Password::registerRule(new SpecialCharacterRule());

new Password('12343.4654j');
```

Comment: This may (or may not) be a bit over-engineered for OP, and I'm not so sure about the names (eg DigitRule for be implies that the input should be all digits) or about the mixing of static and non-static functionality, but the general idea - creating three different checks instead of one hard to read and error-prone regex - is definitely correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain the same level of accuracy and reduce the "step" count (improve efficiency) by replacing `.` with *character classes* / *negated character classes* where appropriate.  As a result of using character classes, you can use greedy quantifiers without negatively impacting accuracy.

Also, by incorporating the `i` flag at the end of your pattern, you can reduce your upper and lower case alphabetical character ranges to one or the other.  `/d` is also shorter than `0-9` (albeit, only by 1 character).

I would recommend this pattern:

```
/^(?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[A-Z\d ]*[^A-Z\d ]).{8,}$/i
```

[PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd7554c5f2d5928820e0012004799769b81ee141)

I've prepared a regex pattern comparison to display the efficiency gains (in terms of steps).  Note, I had to slightly modify your pattern and my recommended pattern to prevent unintended newline matching within the negated character classes.  I have used the same 8 test strings as in my php demo.

My pattern: `/^(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[A-Z\d ]*[^A-Z\d\s]).{8,}$/img` 83 steps [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Zhgh6/1)

OP's pattern: `/^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).{8,}$/mg` 145 steps [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/INB3vm/1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the zero-width lookaheads, you could also use three separate regular expressions. Then you are able to report the violated role to the user:

```
function validate_password($password) {
    if (strlen($password) < 8)
        return "too short";
    if (!preg_match('/\d/', $password))
        return "must contain a digit";
    if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $password))
        return "must contain a special character";
    return true;
}
```

By the way, the third rule rejects autogenerated passwords from password managers, so you should allow these passwords if the length is at least 32.